# AWS Lambda Function Access Denied Error During S3 Put Test Event

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions

I have an AWS Lambda function configured to trigger on an S3 put event. The function is supposed to extract the file name and data from the event and create an entry in a DynamoDB table. The function works as expected when I upload a file to the S3 bucket, but it fails with an "Access Denied" error when I try to test it using an S3 put test event from the AWS Lambda console.

Here is the relevant part of my Lambda function:

```
//... more code before this
export const handler = async (event: any): Promise<void> => {
    const s3Event = event.Records[0].s3;
    const decodedKey = decodeURIComponent(s3Event.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    const params = {
        Bucket: s3Event.bucket.name,
        Key: decodedKey
    };
    const s3Object = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const textData: string = s3Object.Body.toString('utf-8');
    //... more code following this
};
```

Here is my test event:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already configured the necessary read and write permissions for the Lambda function through AWS CDK.

What could be causing the "Access Denied" error during the test event?
Have I missed any necessary configurations or permissions?
Is there anything wrong with the test event JSON that I am using?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're 100% sure that the Lambda function has the necessary permissions (s3:GetObject on arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/mykey) and it works with an S3 event but not your test event then I'd suspect that either the bucket or the key indicated in your test event is the problem. Perhaps the %2F in the key?